# Adding a random number after the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a site which uses jQuery and Ajax to change the site content without reloading the page. The site contains content which I often change. But somehow the page gets saved in the cache so it doesnt show the changes.

I tried several things to make the browser not to save the site into the cache like METAs and PHP. But it doesnt work.

I think it has to do with the fact, that the page always has the same URL so I thought about adding a random number to it like:

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
```

(It's not my code, found it with some googlin) But this only adds the link ID I clicked on to the URL. I don't know where to put "Math.random()" to add a random number.

Hope you can help!

Comment: I don't think adding it to the hash will help, it would need to be on the querystring.

Comment: This defeats http caching purpose.
Please consider changing your http headers before trying to work around it. [List of HTTP header fields from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Comment: The fragment is not sent to the server. I think you want to just put something like "?ts="+(+(new Date)) after your url (a normal url parameter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `cache : false`. jQuery will automatically add a timestamp to the end of the URL for you, making sure that ajax requests are never cached.

Quoting the the API reference for [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> cache
>   Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.

Examples

1. Globally disable caching for all future ajax requests. See [`.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

   ```
   $.ajaxSetup({
     cache: false
   });
   ```
2. Disable caching per request. See [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

   ```
   $.ajax({
     url: "test.html",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
       $("#results").append(html);
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew that! Should I put this right after $(document).ready....?

Comment: Yes you can use `$.ajaxSetup()` right after dom ready though you don't _have_ too. If you have multiple dom ready handlers, you should just put this on the first line of your js file.

Comment: Although I upvoted your answer, is important to know that this will increase traffic. If _often_ change  doesn't mean _always_ change and the response is significantly bigger than pure http headers response (most are), you can save a lot of traffic by using ETags such as `If-Modified-Since`. Http has more to offer than what meets the eye.

Comment: Intresting. But I really don't have a plan about etags. Could you please tell me an example for such a code and where it needs to be inserted? It sounds like META Tags to me...

Comment: An Etag is a unique identifier for a http resource. It can be sent to the browser via an http header. If the resource hasn't change since the browser last made the request, the etag will remain the same. This allows caching of unmodified content. See [HTTP Etag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) and [HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers).

Comment: I meant or instead of such at my last commentary, but now I can't edit it anymore :D. Mausoleum, here is a good introductory article about http [caching in general](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/). Those tags will be inserted in your http requests headers. Your server (such as Apache or ISS) can be fine tunned to best handle it, or Server side languages can be used to manipulate the headers. Those headers have nothing to do with html meta tags, they reside in a header before the body of a http message. [Screen from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Http_request_telnet_ubuntu.png).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery's AJAX functions, try setting `$.ajaxSetup( { cache: false } )` at the top of your page, and let jQuery take care of it for you.

Comment: Thank you, too for giving this advice!

Answer (score 2):

Like most mentionned, you should use the jQuery `cache` parameter, but for your information, it is often done not using `Math.random` but with `new Date().valueOf()`, which is a time value pretty much guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href')
                            .substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5)
                            + Math.random();
```

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to use timestamp with the request:

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href')
                            .substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5)
                            + timestamp;
```