# how to call ajax method recursively

Tags: ajax, jquery, grails

I have a problem in my ajax call.

In the below code, pageReload() function is automatically called when the page gets loaded which in-turn calls the ajaxCall() function for every 10 seconds.

I'm calling a method in grails controller through ajax by passing the parameters needed in the url. The controller method returns an array that contains 3 elements which are the Name of the book, the Author of the book and the year published.

```
<htmL>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function pageReload() {
                var timeInterval = setInterval('ajaxCall()',10000);
            }

            function ajaxCall() {
                jQuery.ajax({    
                    url: '/getBook?rowName=${row}&columnName=${column}',
                    success: function(data){
                        bookReturned(data);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('Error occured in AJAX call');
                    }
                });
            }

            function bookReturned(values){
                alert("Values are : "+values);
            }

            window.onload=pageReload;

        </script>
    <head>
 </html>
```

For every 10 seconds I'm getting the alert for Values which are returned from the controller method. But the controller method is getting executed only for the first call by ajax (I have given println in controller method which gets displayed in console only one time).

How to make the ajax call to execute the controller method every time when it is called.

Please help me in this as I'm new to Grails and ajax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add a timestamp param at the end of your request, so each time you have a unique url, also take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432361/adding-a-random-number-after-the-url)

Comment: Adding timestamp works. But only for first three requests, I'm getting the prints in proper intervals (10 secs). After that (from 4th request) I'm keep on getting prints continously without proper interval. After some time the alert "Error occured in AJAX call" is keep on displaying. Can you please tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: The error function accepts 3 arguments `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )` can you display the type of error your are getting? [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I tried by commenting the alert in bookReturned() function. Now the ajax runs perfectly for every 10 seconds for first two requests. Then it keep on displays the prints in controller method without proper interval.

Comment: Is it possible your controller takes more than 10sec to return ? what kind of task is being done there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requests are being cached. Set the **cache** option to **false**.

> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with
>   HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the
>   GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of
>   requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already
>   been requested by a GET.

See jQuery documentation on [cache here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
jQuery.ajax({    
    cache: false,
    url: '/getBook?rowName=${row}&columnName=${column}',
    success: function(data){
        bookReturned(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error occured in AJAX call');
    }
});
```

Comment: This works. But only for first three requests, I'm getting the prints in proper intervals (10 secs). After that (from 4th request) I'm keep on getting prints continously without proper interval. After some time the alert "Error occured in AJAX call" is keep on displaying. Can you please tell me what is going wrong?