# Javascript Ajax stops working in Chrome after few iterations

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I am breaking my head on an embedded project: Microchip ethernet/ wifi. I have a webpage where the data is loaded via ajax. Due to size limits, I am not using jquery, just Javascript AJAX.

PROBLEM:
It seems to be all good in firefox. But in Chrome, It starts, and If I refresh, the AJAX stops working (sometimes, after repeated refreshes). No error is logged in the console.

I created a stripped down demo on

[pastebin.com/test4/ajaxTest.html](http://pastebin.com/test4/ajaxTest.html). It uses just the `mchp.js` from the microchip demo.  The page loads a number from another page via AJAX. This is repeated 100 ms, and If I cant get anything in 5 seconds ( ie ~50 attempts), it times out.

To `recreate this error`, open the [demo link](http://pastebin.com/test4/ajaxTest.html) in Chrome, and keep refreshing. I have a time out of 5 seconds. I am using `latest version of Chrome`. Appreciate any hints. Thanks.

NOTE: Once it breaks, even if i keep refreshing, it wont work. but if I close the tab and open a new one, it works.

Comment: self inflicted ddos initiating in t-mius 5 minutes

Comment: I was able to free the "block" in the requests by running this command in the JS console: `xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();xmlHttp.open("POST", 'ajaxXML.php', true);xmlHttp.send('');`

After I did this a few seconds later it started working again.

Comment: WireShark shows that after a while, your AJAX code gets `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified` instead of `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. I think the answer gets cached by Chrome. Check out the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432361/adding-a-random-number-after-the-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WireShark shows that after a while, your AJAX code gets `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified` instead of `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. I think the answer gets cached by Chrome. You could append a random number argument to the URL to prevent caching (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432361/adding-a-random-number-after-the-url)).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @kol, figured it was a cache issue. So I have modified the url with a random number in the argument. Seems to be working now.

Comment: @kol I posted an answer bcz there was none (thought you deserve the credit). If you can post your comment as an answer, Would definitely mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
var xmlhttp=false;  
try{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch(e){       
try{            
xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch(e){
try{
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
catch(e1){
xmlhttp=false;
}
}
}

return xmlhttp;
}

function getdef()
{
alert('str');
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("def1").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
```